# Anchor link offset by JQuery slider

Tags: jquery, anchor, offset

My "NEWS" page is an anchor link to news posts futher down on the "HOME" page. When users visit the NEWS link it goes to the correct position but is then offset by the JQuery slider which loads a little later than everything else.

Check out the problem here: http://dthudson.com/ccr/

Any idea how to fix this? BTW my JS is being loaded in the head.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<a id="news-stuff"> ..... </a>
```

instead of:

```
<a id="" name="news-stuff"> ..... </a>
```

Comment: Tested it out - its acting the same.